# Handling Cypress url redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress, end-to-end

I have a Cypress test which clicks on an image causing a redirect to a specific url. The test then checks the url contains a specific string.

However, clicking this image causes the tests to stop/fail with a "Whoops, there is no test to run." message when the redirect happens.

The Cypress test is very simple:

```
/* global describe, it, cy */
import loadStory from '../../../config/cypress/helpers/loadStory'

const component = 'product-card'
const productCardImage = '[data-test=component-product-card_imageContainer]'

describe(`${component} component interaction tests`, () => {
  it('clicking the image should open the products page', () => {
    loadStory(component, 'Default')
    cy.get(productCardImage).should('be.visible')
    cy.get(productCardImage).click()
    cy.url().should('contain', '/product')
  })
})
```

My tests run on `http://localhost:9002` and it seems that redirecting to `http://localhost:9002/product/productId` while the test suit is running is what causes Cypress to crash/fail and instead Cypress tries to go to `https://localhost:9002/__/`

I am wondering how I can click this image and redirect to the url without causing this crash/fail in Cypress.

Comment: You can set follow redirect = false in visit or request

Comment: Ive been playing around and now have the image inside an a tag with an href. This didn't explicitly fix the problem, however explicitly adding target _self to the a tag has fixed it. As of yet I have no idea why that is.

Comment: Have you try to do similar this ? cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/newthing/:id')

Comment: Yes I have - because cypress redirected the entire browser it seemed, looking for the location always failed. For some reason target _self is the only way to get around this.

Comment: In this case, you should start your test with authentication calls and open http://localhost:9002/product/productId. If you don't know ids, in this case, make API calls and add products and open with that Ids

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Hi @John, I did yes - I had to explicitly add target _self to the a tag. I am still unsure why this was but it seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain is not supported in Cypress.

Example:
step 1: You navigate to google
step 2: Search for Gmail
step 3: clicked on gmail link

You are switching from Google.com to gmail.com - cypress doesn't support this.

Workaround 1:
You can remove set href attribute value to blank as below:

target="_blank"
so that it will open in same page.

Workaround 2:

put step 1 and step 2 in one test iteration

and put step 3 in another iteration

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rajan. Its not cross domain though, it's on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Their is an issue of `http` to `https`.

[image: See Attached]