# Cypress: Login Authentication redirects to another domain: Workaround?

Tags: authentication, redirect, cypress

I understand that Cypress does not allow flipping from one domain to another domain because it will error with:

```
chrome-error://chromewebdata/
```

However, I need a workaround. I am providing a test set for multiple environments: STAGE, DEMO, PROD.

With **DEMO** and **PROD**, during the authentication phase (username/password), stay within the same domain:

- **VISIT**: `https://[demo|www].foo.com`
- **AUTH**: `https://account.foo.com/auth` >> username >> password
- **CONSENT**: `https://[demo|www].foo.com/action...`

With **STAGE**, the authentication phase flips to another domain:

- **VISIT**: `https://[stage].foo.com`
- **AUTH**: `https://account.bar.com/auth` >> username >> password
- **CONSENT**: `https://[stage].foo.com/action...`

Thereby, Cypress fails to redirect from **VISIT** to **AUTH** because of domain flip. This is blocking testing of **STAGE**.

What recommended workaround approaches?

- Puppeteer?
- Native Cypress using `cy.request()`?

Referenced:

- [Handling Cypress url redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476816/handling-cypress-url-redirect)
- [Error with authentication in e2e tests using cypress: chrome-error://chromewebdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61259933/error-with-authentication-in-e2e-tests-using-cypress-chrome-error-chromewebda)

Thank you, much appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I took is similar to the Cypress Recipe [Login with CSRF token](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens)

As mentioned, each deployment has its own **website URL** followed by **account login URL**.

Needed first is the [CSRF](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf) token from **account login** page, which its URL is referred here as `$baseUrl`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('cmdGetCSRF', ($baseUrl) => {
    cy.log('COMMAND cmdGetCSRF');

    expect($baseUrl)
        .to.be.a('string')
        .not.empty

    cy.request($baseUrl)
        .its('body')
        .then(($body) => {
            const $html = Cypress.$($body)

            cy.log('html', $html)

            const csrf = $html.find('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()

            expect(csrf)
                .to.be.a('string')
                .not.empty

            return cy.wrap(csrf)
        })
})
```

Then within `body` of `requestOptions` provided to `cy.request()` which will performing the login, provide one-time CSRF token:

```
    const body: { [key: string]: string } = {
        email: $envCypress.account_username,
        password: $envCypress.account_password,
        __RequestVerificationToken: $csrfToken
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has recently add a new experimental feature for running test on multiple origins [here](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2022/04/25/cypress-9-6-0-easily-test-multi-domain-workflows-with-cy-origin). There are examples for cross origin login too. More on `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` feature:

- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin
- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session